# Trouble running this simple cronjob on the server every 24 hours. What is wrong?

Tags: centos, permissions, unix, cron, scheduled-task

Trying to run an 'R' script at 00:30 every day. The script is located in /home/username/Desktop/folder/runnow.r and `which Rscript` reveals that the absolute path to binary Rscript is `/usr/bin/Rscript`. The crontab entry that I made was using the `crontab -e` command and then inserting the line:

`38 14 * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/username/Desktop/folder/runnow.r`

Time right now is 14:36 of course. And I wait 5 minutes to see if a CSV file is created in my home folder. Since the R script runnow.r has instructions to process some data and then create a CSV file in the home folder.

But there's no CSV file in my home folder. When I manually run this script (without using cron), it does create a CSV in my home folder. So I know there's nothing wrong with the script. I am using absolute paths everywhere and I have even tried restarting the crond using `service crond restart`. However, no luck. Is this a privileges issue? Does crond not have enough privileges to create a CSV in my own home folder?

EDIT: NEW OBSERVATION

If I change the line to `* * * * * /usr/bin/Rscript /home/username/Desktop/foldername/runme.r` instead of specifying the exact time, it does create the right CSV file in the right location. So `* * * * *` works and `54 13 * * *` doesn't. Why?

Comment: What does the syslog contain around the time the script should run?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out after the last observation I made regarding time. This is going to make me look silly, but I had gotten the time wrong. I'm testing this cronjob in a virtual machine that has a time different from my host machine. I was scheduling the job in the virtual machine, and looking at the time on my host machine. Both times being different meant that script didn't execute on the time I expected it too.

Comment: Yet another argument for UTC everywhere!

Comment: `This is going to make me look silly, but I had gotten the time wrong` Never be ashamed to make mistakes. You figured out what was wrong and I bet you are unlikely to make that mistake again. Thumbs up emoji.